# MongoDB - group by on facet result

Tags: mongodb, grouping, facet

Provided I have following collections

Customers

```
[
    {
      uuid: "first",
      culture: "it-it"
    },
    {
      uuid: "second",
      culture: "de-de"
    }
]
```

Vehicles

```
[
    {
      model: "mymodel",
      users: [
        {
          uuid: "first",
          isOwner: true,
          createdOn: "2019-05-15T06: 00: 00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      model: "mymodel",
      users: [
        {
          uuid: "first",
          isOwner: false,
          createdOn: "2019-05-15T06: 00: 00"
        },
        {
          uuid: "second",
          isOwner: true,
          createdOn: "2019-05-15T06: 00: 00"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

And following query:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vehicles",
      let: {
        uuid: "$uuid"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$uuid",
                "$users.uuid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            model: 1,
            users: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$users",
                as: "user",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$user.uuid",
                    "$$uuid"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$users"
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              isOwner: "$users.isOwner",
              createdOn: "$users.createdOn"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "vehicles"
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      "createdOn": [
        {
          $match: {
            "vehicles": {
              $elemMatch: {
                isOwner: true,
                $and: [
                  {
                    "createdOn": {
                      $gte: "2019-05-15T00: 00: 00"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "createdOn": {
                      $lt: "2019-05-16T00: 00: 00"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            culture: 1,
            count: {
              $size: "$vehicles"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: 0,
            "total": {
              $sum: "$count"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "CreatedOn": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$CreatedOn.total",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I get following result:

```
[
  {
    "createdOn": 2
  }
]
```

What I would like to achieve is a result as follows:

```
[
    {
        culture: "it-it",
        results: {
            "createdOn": 1
        }
    },
    {
        culture: "de-de",
        results: {
            "createdOn": 1
        }
    }
]
```

But I cannot seem to figure out where I can group so that I can get that result.
Can someone show me the way to do this?

The query is more complex with more metrics so this is a trimmed down version of what I have.

I tried grouping everywhere but fail to get the desired result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "vehicles",
      "let": {
        "uuid": "$uuid"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $unwind: "$users"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$users.uuid", "$$uuid"]
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$users.isOwner", true]
                },
                {
                  $gte: ["$users.createdOn", "2019-05-15T00: 00: 00"]
                },
                {
                  $lte: ["$users.createdOn", "2019-05-16T00: 00: 00"]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $count:"totalVehicles"
        }
      ],
      as: "vehiclesInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$vehiclesInfo",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$culture",
      "culture": {
        $first: "$culture"
      },
      "createdOn": {
        $sum: "$vehiclesInfo.totalVehicles"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "culture": 1,
      "results.createdOn": "$createdOn"
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Output:**

```
{ "culture" : "de-de", "results" : { "createdOn" : 1 } }
{ "culture" : "it-it", "results" : { "createdOn" : 1 } }
```